# JavaScript on iPad needs regular reboot of network connectivity

Tags: javascript, ipad, networking

One website I regularly access on my iPad has various JavaScript elements which stop working after around 15 minutes of use (it appears not to be after a set number of actions, if I do one interaction then leave it 15 minutes I have the same problem).

The problem happens on two different iPads on the same network. A fairly old iPad 3 with latest iOS 9.3.5 and a brand new iPad Mini 2 also with latest iOS. If I use mobile internet connection (tethered to my phone) rather than my in-house Wifi I don't have the problem.

The problem doesn't occur on desktop browsers, even when running as an iPad by updating the agent.

The website owners are supposedly investigating, but have said they can't recreate on their mobile test devices. Don't know how hard they have tried mind you!

Originally I though that the only thing that can make the website work again was to switch off and power on again the iPad. Closing the tabs, or the whole browser, or clearing history etc, makes no difference, only powering off and on again. I have more recently figured out that just disconnecting from the network and reconnecting, then reloading the page appears to reload the failing Javascript elements.

Using private browsing until the problem occurs and then closing down the tab, leaving private browsing, and then re-entering has certainly cleared all information as I have to login to the website again, but the problem persists.

So my question is, what could a network do to stop loading javascript parts of a webpage that disconnecting and reconnecting would fix? i.e. what might I have to fix on my home network? If there is any other information I can give, please do let me know.

Comment: So you are saying that if you close the browser on the iPad (Safari, right?) and restart it, that's not enough you must restart the entire device?

Comment: It could be anything from your session to the website, to SessionStorage, to cookies, to a bad state, to JavaScript errors which could cause a script to stop working. It's very hard to tell you what is going on without actually doing some investigating.

Comment: @scott-Marcus yes that's exactly what I'm saying. No combination of closing tabs, the browser, clearing history etc in safari settings makes any difference. Only restarting the device helps.

Comment: @Dymos I know it's a long shot, I guess I was hoping that there wasn't much that only got cleared on a device restart. Is there any investigation I can do? The website owners don't seem to be doing much visible! I can recreate the problem 4 times an hour, so I am happy to try anything you can give me pointers to.

Comment: @MoragHughson the amount of investigation you can do depends entirely on how comfortable you are with debugging the client-side web application, I will say though that trying to do it on an iPad wouldn't be a fun experience (IMO, I guess some people enjoy it :P). If the problems occur on a desktop browser like Chrome or Firefox as well then it might be a bit easier. One thing you could try is to use [Private browsing in Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203036) and then using the website, then if you close that tab, cookie/history/sessionStorage/etc. should all be cleared.

Comment: @MoragHughson I think we need to know what iPad version you have and what Safari version it's running.

Comment: @Dymos Thanks for responding. Have added details to my question. Will give private browsing a shot and report back. At the very least it's behaviour may narrow down what data is cleared/not cleared as a result.

Comment: @Dymos I tried private browsing but the problem persists. What kind of cached information for JavaScript is not cleared by ending the privately browsed tab that is cleared by restarting the device?

Comment: I can't really think of anything that would stick around in private mode once it's closed. If you're requiring a device reboot still even when using private mode that kind of has me stumped (mind, I am by no means an expert on iOS or safari related issues, or precisely how its private browsing works). Do you see the same issue on other browsers on iOS?

Comment: @Dymos - I installed Chrome on the iPad at the suggestion of the website owners, and thought to myself - yay! at least this way I will get 2 x 15 minutes before I need to reboot. But no. Whatever state is getting messed up, it is shared between the browsers. Once it is bust in one browser, it is also bust in the other one. I can use the website in either browser until it breaks, but once broken it is broken everywhere. So - any shared javascript state?

Comment: Hmm maybe they're using same WebView in the background so that the only effective difference is the browser UI/features but the same rendering/JS engine. If you're keen to dive deeper and have a Mac you could try to [debug using Web Inspector](http://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/) to see if there are any JS errors. You'll also be able to see any storage for the application (Cookies, Session Storage, and Local Storage). If you use the app for a while until it stops working, hopefully you'll see something in there that'll stand out.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Mac. Ah well, it was a long shot that someone could figure it out based on what little info I was able provide. Thanks for your assistance @Dymos

Comment: Discovered some more detail about the failure, so updated the question on the off-chance that it suggests something new to anyone reading this.